# Can you export all layer comps as JPG without Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

We have various other parts of the business who want to view Photoshop designs that make use of layer comps but don't have Photoshop. The expense of a Photoshop license just for this is not justifiable. This leaves a tedious task of exporting JPGs each time the Photoshops are updated (I know there is a script but it's still tedious due to the regularity of changes).

Is it possible to export layer comps from a PSD without Photoshop? Alternatively is it possible to automate the process whenever the file is changed?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer to this if anyone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a way to view Photoshop files without having to purchase a full license? If I'm reading this correctly, you want a designer to be able to create a comp in Photoshop, send it along to others for review, and let the designer(s) make those changes?

There are several free apps (IrfanView and Quicktime are the ones that come immediately to mind) that allow you to view Photoshop files. Just download and install one of those to the reviewers' desktops and put the Photoshop files in a shared folder.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a free way to view the layer comps within a Photoshop file. I'm aware of a number of apps that let you view the layers. Paint.net would be my recommendation.